# What part of the Census Block is the County?

Tags: data, geocoding, census, terminology, county

I have a list of census blocks for California and I am trying to get the county for each row.

If I have a census block of 60070004024003, which 2 digits make up the county FIPS?

Answer (score 4):

Your example is missing one character (it is 15 in total). In California it should be `060070004024003` (starting with `06`; see [here](http://proximityone.com/geo_blocks.htm)).

The first and second digits identify the state. The third, fourth and fifth ones identify the county within the state. So, `06007` gives a unique identifier for a county ([source](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/geoidentifiers.html)).

Assuming you have a list in a spreadsheet (Excel, for example), column A. Type in B1:

```
= LEFT(A1,5)
```